# Elemental problem of dynamics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram, string

Ok, let's go fast. If we have the following system, and we want it to be static (acceleration = 0), we will always and obligatorily need friction, or any other force to oppose those existing in the body that rests on the surface, so we can affirm that the system shown in the image can never be static in the way it is proposed,   truth? (This taking into account that the pulley also has no friction)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let M be the mass on the flat surface and m be the mass hanging. Assume equilibrium.  The force balance on m is $$(1)T = mg$$  The horizontal force balance on M is $$(2)F_f = T$$ where $$(3)F_f = \mu_sN$$ is the force of friction on M, $N$ is the normal force on M, and $\mu_s$ is the maximum force of static friction on M. The vertical force balance on M is $$(4)N = Mg$$  Equilibrium is achieved if $$(5) m \le \mu_sM$$

Comment: Ok, that answer was unspectecly good. Just wow...

Comment: The key is to recognize the best "systems" to consider; here two systems: m and M, not the combined system m and M.  This trick is used many times to simplify physics problems.

Comment: Obviously it will be that way, but in the case there is not μ ( μ = 0), so the mass of the hanging body must be negative to achieve the equilibrium, but anyway, your explaination was so good... Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: You can use `\tag` to make equation numbers.

Comment: Thanks @Rob; did not know that!

Comment: One other point. Consider the system as the combined m, M, rope and pully. Gravity acts down on m and M and friction acts to the left on M, and N acts up on M. Since we know there is equilibrium from the earlier analysis separately on m, then M, there must be other forces here. The other forces are from the pully on the rope which provides both a horizontal force to the right and a vertical force up equal to mg to maintain equilibrium.